# Can't access index in folder when rewrite engine removes .php and .html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem accessing index files when rewrite engine removes `.php` and `.html`...

I have an index in **"public_html/user/username/index.php"**
But it throws me to error page when I'm trying to access either

**mydomain.com/user/username** or

**mydomain.com/user/username/index** or

**mydomain.com/user/username/index.php**

When I'm trying to reach any file from folder in public_html folder let's say

**public_html/user/username.php** == **mydomain.com/user/username** <-- WORKS

What is going on?

**My .htaccess :**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

*Rewrite engine is already on and everything works perfectly...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for presence of php and html files before adding those etenstions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```